# How to disable system-wide low battery alert in app

Tags: swift

When iOS system remaining battery falls to 20% or 10%, it shows a low battery alert. How can I disable it when my app is running?

Comment: Very simple: *You can't.*

Comment: There is no API that allows a developer to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this on non-jailbroken devices. Don't look for workarounds, because there aren't any. The low battery warning is an important system alert, and cannot be disabled.

I also can't see any valid reasons to do this. If you are making a game or some other entertainment app, and don't want the user's experience to be interrupted, you should respond to your app losing focus (`applicationDidEnterBackground`) to pause the game, so the game doesn't continue while the alert is being displayed.